# 4151 frequency to voltage converter

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

[image]

The above diagram is the inner circuitry of the [4151 from the datasheet](https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/529399.pdf?_ga=2.24788218.1519298210.1506157864-2116811814.1506157864).

This IC is used for precise voltage to frequency and frequency to voltage conversion.

What are the values of the resistors in the datasheet? I wish to simulate the voltage to frequency function and the frequency to voltage function using this chip in LTspice.

Comment: You won't find the answer because it will be intellectual property I expect.

Answer (score 3):

The resistor values won't do you much good.  They'd only be valid when used with transistors that have the same parameters as the ones on the chip - and you don't have those.

I'm not even sure you could replicate it with discrete components.  Some of those resistors aren't simple resistors:

[image]

That thing seems to imply some kind of variable resistor - or maybe some kind of pickup to detect the voltage at that point.

Whatever it is, you won't be duplicating it with real components or in LTspice without a lot more detail on what it is and how it is used.

If you want to learn about how voltage to frequency converters work, I'd suggest finding an example circuit made using discrete components (op-amps and other ICs together with passives) to study.

If you are interested in what happens at the transistor level, there are also voltage to frequency circuits made from individual transistors and diodes.

The internal circuitry of an IC is rarely a good example to follow for discrete components.